# make menu bars in fixed div clickable

Tags: javascript, css, menu, clickable

So I have trouble with clicking a div container, to close my menu. Whenever I click on the "p" area it works, but if I click on the transformed "X" bars it won't. I even tried giving each element an z-index. Does anyone know why the click won't work over the "X"?

Note: I do have 2 Overlay I-Frames with this "Close X" element.

Here is my SCSS:

```
.closeIframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 4%;
    right: 4%;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 200;

    p {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .xWrap {
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 199;
        height: 20px;

        .x {
            width: 20px;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: $color-black;
        }

        .crossTop {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 10px);
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 10px);
        }

        .crossBottom {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="impressumOverlay" class="iframe">
    <div class="closeIframe">
        <p class="upperC">Close</p>
        <div class="xWrap">
            <div class="x crossTop">
            </div>
            <div class="x crossBottom">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="impressumIframe" src="impressum.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Snippet from JS:

```
var impressumIframe = document.getElementById('impressumOverlay');

function addListeners() {
    var closeIframe = document.querySelectorAll('.closeIframe');
    for (var l = 0; l < closeIframe.length; l++) {
        closeIframe[l].addEventListener('click', closeIframes, false);
    }
}

function closeIframes(e) {
    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id === "impressumOverlay") {
        impressumIframe.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

addListeners();
```

Comment: Did your css styles work, looks more like a sass styles. Remove your closeIframes function from addListeners and declare it outside. Also when do you call the function addListeners() ??

Comment: addListeners() is called right after all Images were preloaded in the construct. I fixed the  formatting here. I had a few copy/paste errors here that you pointed out.